# How to output a value in an html.div?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a function that prints a random value.
The function is 'activated' when the button `Start` is pressed.

```
            print("acquisition is on")
            print(random.random())
```

At the moment the random value is printed in the console. But I am wondering how to directly output this value in the html.Div.

Below is the full code

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, ctx
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import time
import threading
import random


app = Dash(
    __name__,
    external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.FONT_AWESOME],
    title = 'MT',
    prevent_initial_callbacks = "initial_duplicate"
)



class Nanotec(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # When Main is excuted, this does :
        super(Nanotec, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__flag = threading.Event() # The flag used to pause the thread
        self.__flag.set() # Set to True
        self.__running = threading.Event() # Used to stop the thread identification
        self.__running.set() # Set running to True
        

    def run(self):
        while self.__running.isSet():
            self.__flag.wait() # return immediately when it is True, block until the internal flag is True when it is False
            print("acquisition is on")
            print(random.random())
            time.sleep(1)


    def pause(self):
        self.__flag.clear() # Set to False to block the thread
        print("pausing")

    def resume(self):
        self.__flag.set() # Set to True, let the thread stop blocking
        print("resuming")

    def stop(self):
        self.__flag.set() # Resume the thread from the suspended state, if it is already suspended
        self.__running.clear() # Set to False


@app.callback(Output('container', 'children'),
              Input('btn_start_nanotec', 'n_clicks'),
              Input('btn_pause_nanotec', 'n_clicks'),
              Input('btn_resume_nanotec', 'n_clicks')
              )
def display(btn_start_nanotec, btn_pause_nanotec, btn_resume_nanotec):
        button_id = ctx.triggered_id if not None else 'No clicks yet'
        if button_id == "btn_start_nanotec" :
            my_thread_nanotec.start()
        elif button_id == "btn_pause_nanotec" :
            my_thread_nanotec.pause()
        elif button_id == "btn_resume_nanotec" :
            my_thread_nanotec.resume()

my_thread_nanotec = Nanotec()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Start', id='btn_start_nanotec'),
    html.Button('Pause', id='btn_pause_nanotec'),
    html.Button('Resume', id='btn_resume_nanotec'),
    html.Div(id='container'),
    html.Br(),

])

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run_server(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what are you trying to do here regarding that multithreading class.  Is it supposed to update `html.Div` one time per second?  Is text supposed to be updated on button click?

But since the question is **"How to put a value…"**, here's a quick explanation.  I replaced multithreading class with a simple generator to make things clearer.
Your callback is supposed to *return* the value to put into `html.Div`.  So here the value is fetched from the generator (when the button is clicked) and returned:

```
import random
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, ctx


app = Dash(__name__, title="MT", prevent_initial_callbacks="initial_duplicate")

def randoms():
    while True:
        yield random.random()


random_iter = randoms()


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="container", component_property="children"),
    Input("btn_start_nanotec", "n_clicks"),
    Input("btn_pause_nanotec", "n_clicks"),
    Input("btn_resume_nanotec", "n_clicks"),
)
def display(*_):
    button_id = ctx.triggered_id
    if button_id == "btn_start_nanotec":
        result = next(random_iter)
    elif button_id == "btn_pause_nanotec":
        result = 'Pause?..'
    elif button_id == "btn_resume_nanotec":
        result = next(random_iter)
    return result


app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button("Start", id="btn_start_nanotec"),
        html.Button("Pause", id="btn_pause_nanotec"),
        html.Button("Resume", id="btn_resume_nanotec"),
        html.Div(id="container"),
        html.Br(),
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

You can replace my super-simple iterator with anything else (`threading.Thread`, `multiprocessing.Pool`, whatever), but the callback still has to get the value from the source and return it.

#### Intervals

If you need to update the output periodically (once per second), take a look into [Intervals](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval).  The same basic principle works just the same (callback returns value), but it would handle periodical updates for you.

#### Updating Input with Websocket messages

[`Websocket` component](https://www.dash-extensions.com/components/websocket) seems to fit the bill quite nicely: data sent by another process/thread and updated in (sort of) real time, even bidirectional communication (pause/resume) is supported.

Comment: I may be wrong but the code does not work :-( UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Comment: Thanks. The multithreading class is supposed to control a device that can update a value every x seconds. Here your code only outputs one value and does not automatically outputs a value every xx second.

Comment: `UnboundLocalError` does appear for me as well, but I couldn't figure out why.  But it still works.

Comment: @2WFR, have you noticed the "Intervals" section at the bottom?  I think, it might be your best bet.  From what I gather, Dash isn't super friendly to state changes from "outside".

Comment: I will have a look, thanks. Meanwhile I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023807/keeping-dcc-intervals-firing-while-browser-tab-is-in-background-for-a-plotly-das. Using redis might be a solution

Comment: @2WFR, good catch! I saw this question, but its summary didn't look promising, so I missed the meaty part.  I did a bit of digging, and I'd say Redis is a bit of an overkill, but Websocket component looks promising.  I've added a section about it to the answer.

Comment: Just have posted a working solution

Comment: @2WFR, well done, I've upvoted yours as well :)

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION (Working example)**
using a redis server (https://redis.io/docs/install/install-redis/).

Thanks to :

[Thread that I can pause and resume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640283/thread-that-i-can-pause-and-resume)

[Keeping dcc.Intervals firing while browser tab is in background for a Plotly Dash application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023807/keeping-dcc-intervals-firing-while-browser-tab-is-in-background-for-a-plotly-das)

https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks

- Structure

```
workspace/
├── MT_W/
│   ├── .venv/
│   ├── MT_devices/
│   │   └── lib_Nanotec_v0.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── MyDash_v0/
│   │   ├── MT_dashcallback_v0.py
│   │   └── MT_dashlayout_v0.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── MT_master_v0.py
```

- **init**.py (MT_devices)

```
from .lib_Nanotec_v0 import *
```

- lib_Nanotec_v0.py

```
import threading
import redis as r
import time
import random
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=10)

class Nanotec(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # When Main is excuted, this does :
        super(Nanotec, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__flag = threading.Event() # The flag used to pause the thread
        self.__flag.set() # Set to True
        self.__running = threading.Event() # Used to stop the thread identification
        self.__running.set() # Set running to True
        
    def run(self):
        while self.__running.isSet():
            self.__flag.wait() # return immediately when it is True, block until the internal flag is True when it is False
            # This is where I read the sensor
            r.set("mysensor_Nanotec", random.randint(1, 10))
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def pause(self):
        self.__flag.clear() # Set to False to block the thread
        print("pausing")

    def resume(self):
        self.__flag.set() # Set to True, let the thread stop blocking
        print("resuming")

    def stop(self):
        self.__flag.set() # Resume the thread from the suspended state, if it is already suspended
        self.__running.clear() # Set to False
```

- **init**.py (MyDash_v0)

```
from .MT_dashlayout_v0 import *
from .MT_dashcallback_v0 import *
```

- MT_dashcallback_v0.py

```
from dash import Input, Output, ctx
import redis
import MT_devices


# Connect to redis on database 10
r = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=10)
# Define thread
my_thread_nanotec = MT_devices.Nanotec()
 
# Callbacks       
def get_callbacks(app,):
    @app.callback(Output('container', 'children'),
                Input('btn_start_nanotec', 'n_clicks'),
                Input('btn_pause_nanotec', 'n_clicks'),
                Input('btn_resume_nanotec', 'n_clicks')
                )
    def display(btn_start_nanotec, btn_pause_nanotec, btn_resume_nanotec):
            button_id = ctx.triggered_id if not None else "No clicks yet"
            if button_id == "btn_start_nanotec" :
                my_thread_nanotec.start()
            elif button_id == "btn_pause_nanotec" :
                my_thread_nanotec.pause()
            elif button_id == "btn_resume_nanotec" :
                my_thread_nanotec.resume()

    @app.callback(Output("result", "figure"), [Input("poller", "n_intervals")])
    def poll_result(n_intervals):
        # Get sensor value.
        sensor_value = r.get("mysensor_Nanotec").decode("utf-8")
        # Create graph.
        return dict(data=[dict(x=[0], y=[int(sensor_value)], type="bar")],
                    layout=dict(yaxis=dict(range=[0, 10]), title="Sensor value"))
```

- MT_dashlayout_v0.py

```
from dash import  html, dcc

def def_input_groups():
    nanotec_input =  html.Div([
        html.Button('Start', id='btn_start_nanotec'),
        html.Button('Pause', id='btn_pause_nanotec'),
        html.Button('Resume', id='btn_resume_nanotec'),
        html.Div(id='container'),
        html.Br(),
    ])
    return nanotec_input

def def_figure():
    figure  =  html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="result"), dcc.Interval(id="poller", interval=500)
    ])
    return figure
```

- MT_master_v0.py

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from flask import Flask

import MyDash_v0 as MyDash

# Start app
server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.FONT_AWESOME],
    title = 'MT',
    prevent_initial_callbacks = "initial_duplicate"
)

# Define layout
app.layout = dbc.Container([
    MyDash.def_input_groups(),
    MyDash.def_figure(),
    ], fluid=True,)

# Get callbakcs
MyDash.get_callbacks(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run_server(debug = True)
```

I am sure this can be improved but this works for my purpose.

Basically the Start button allows to read a sensor (its value is sent to the redis database).
One can pause or resume the acquisition at any time.

[image: Display]